# Если мне нужно чтобы было несколько полей в дереве то как их заполнить с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct tree {
    int ticket_code;
    int numberofthings;
    int luggage_weight;
    string last_name;
    tree* left,* right;
};
using namespace std;
void create_tree(tree** p, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        *p = NULL;
    }
    else
    {

        tree* newP = new tree;
        cout << "VVedi ticket_code: ";
        cin >> newP->ticket_code;
        cout << "VVedi numberofthings: ";
        cin >> newP->numberofthings;
        cout << "VVedi luggage_weight: ";
        cin >> newP->luggage_weight;
        cout << "VVedi lastname: ";
        cin >> newP->last_name;
        int
            nl = n / 2,
            nr = n - nl - 1;
        create_tree(&newP->left, nl);
        create_tree(&newP->right, nr);
        *p = newP;
    }
}
void print2DUtil(tree* root, int space)
{
    int COUNT = 0;
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    space += COUNT;

    print2DUtil(root->right, space);


    cout << endl;
    for (int i = COUNT; i < space; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << root->ticket_code << "\n";
    cout << root->numberofthings << "\n";
    cout << root->luggage_weight << "\n";
    cout << root->last_name << "\n";

    print2DUtil(root->left, space);
}
void print2D(tree* root)
{
    print2DUtil(root, 0);
}
int getSum(tree* root, int& elements)
{
    ++elements;
    int sum = root->ticket_code;
    if (root->left != NULL)
        sum += getSum(root->left, elements);
    if (root->right != NULL)
        sum += getSum(root->right, elements);
    return sum;
}
int getAverage(tree* root)
{
    int sum = 0; 
    int elements = 0; 
    sum = getSum(root, elements); 
    return sum / elements;
}
void deleteTree(tree* node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;

    deleteTree(node->left);
    deleteTree(node->right);
    cout << "\n Deleting node: " << node->ticket_code;
    delete node;
}
void deleteBinaryTree(tree*& root)
{
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    deleteBinaryTree(root->left);
    deleteBinaryTree(root->right);

    delete root;

    root = nullptr;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    tree* root;
    cout << "VVedi razmer: ";
    cin >> n;
    create_tree(&root, n);
    print2D(root);
    int average = getAverage(root);
    cout << endl;
    cout << average;
    deleteBinaryTree(root);
    if (root == nullptr) {
        cout << "Tree Successfully Deleted";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`tree`
 `----`
`1`    `<-- root`
`/`   `\`
`2`     `3`
`/` 
`4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить ввод, как уже делаете для поля `data`. Неплохо было бы также выводить сообщение, что надо ввести:

```
struct tree {
  int data;
  int data2; //Новое поле
  tree* left, *right;
};

void create_tree(tree** p, int n)
....
  else
  {
    tree* newP = new tree;
    cout << "VVedi data: ";
    cin >> newP->data;   //Ввод значения старого поля
    cout << "VVedi data2: ";
    cin >> newP->data2;  //Ввод значения нового поля
```

Для вывода элементов дерева со смещением надо изменить функцию вывода так:

```
void print2DUtil(tree* root, int space)
{
  int COUNT = 2;
  if (root == NULL)
    return;

  //Создаем строку из space пробелов.
  std::string indent(space, ' ');
  cout << indent << root->ticket_code << "\n";
  cout << indent << root->numberofthings << "\n";
  cout << indent << root->luggage_weight << "\n";
  cout << indent << root->last_name << "\n";

  print2DUtil(root->right, space + COUNT);
  print2DUtil(root->left, space + COUNT);
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Насколько я понял, программа сначала запрашивает количество элементов и создает такое количество узлов в бинарном дереве. При создании каждого из узлов она запрашивает значения всех полей узла, в ответе это два поля. Поля left и right служебные и инициализируются программой, а не пользователем.

Comment: В вопросе нет кода вывода, что-то дописали?

Comment: Выводит два элемента, это не отдельные деревья. Все элементы имеют один корень - переменная tree в функции main.

Comment: Можете показать пример, как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Все верно. Просто между разными элементами нет разделителей. На 5 элементах будет нагляднее.